# How to validate email address form input in react

Tags: html, reactjs, validation

HTML5 input elements of type `email` can already validate that the input given is a valid email address.  How can I exploit this in my react app, thereby avoiding writing a regular expression or some other equally poor solution?

My react is using functional components (not sure if this detail is important)

I've tried giving my input element an input, and then using `document.getElementById('foo').validity.valid` but of course the element doesn't exist at any point where my code can use it.

My onChange handler is

```
onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)}
```

This just sets whatever invalid data happens to be in the input element.

Note to those who would vote to close as duplicate - I've found and read all the so-called duplicates.  They are all asked in general terms, ie, JavaScript in general, not as applies specifically to react, and/or they are either answered as "write some hairy regex", or "use some 3rd party library", both which amount to "reinvent the wheel, badly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple, `event.target` is a reference to the input element; it has your `validity` property.  Just store `event.target.validity.valid` in your component state alongside the `event.target.value`.

```
onChange={event => {
    setEmail(event.target.value)
    setValidEmail(event.target.validity.valid)
}}
```

Comment: Lovely, works like a charm, I would personally rename it to `setIsEmailValid` to indicate its boolean nature

Comment: P.S If you ever need the message itself, for example to change the default styling it's `event.target.validationMessage`